# Use query builder in form CollectionType

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Is it possible to use a query builder or something else in my collectionType ?

Comment: have you try injections?

Comment: No.
How to do ?

Comment: Yes you can. But why do you want it? Please explain your use case, to prevent the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options as explained in this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html) after that you could use the entity_manager to extract your data from database and fill your collection.

Give it a try and hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change my getter in my entity to only have the data I wanted
Thank you