# Use query_builder on CollectionType in symfony4 forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In a symfony 4 form, I need to use something like a `query_builder` option that is available on `EntityType` but from a `CollectionType`. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355784/use-query-builder-in-form-collectiontype) with no good answers.

In my project, each `Site` entity has many `Goal`. Each `Goal` has a numeric goal and a specific date. I'd like to edit the goals of a site for a specific date only. The problem is that a CollectionType form pulls *all* goals to show in the form, but I only want to pull the goals for a given date. How? There is no `query_builder` on a `CollectionType` like there is on an `EntityType`. I could change the getter in my Site entity, but I don't know how to pass the needed date to my getter.

For now my work-around is to render the entire form (with ALL associated goals for a given site), and then use some javascript to hide all goals except those with the date to edit. This works, but it's a terrible solution for sites with lots of goals spanning a range of dates.

My `Site` entity (only relevant code is shown):

```
class Site
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->goals = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Goal", mappedBy="site") */
    private $goals;


    public function getGoals()
    {
        return $this->goals;
    }
}
```

and my related `Goal` entity:

```
class Goal
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="date") */
    private $goalDate;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $goal;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Site", inversedBy="goals") */
    private $site;

    // ...
}
```

My forms:

```
class SiteGoalsAdminForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('goals', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => GoalsEmbeddedForm::class,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Site::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

and the individual goal form:

```
class GoalsEmbeddedForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('goal', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('goalDate', DateType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Goal::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that the [`allow_add` and `allow_delete`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) options for `CollectionType` imply that submitted form data pertains to *all* the entities in the collection. Editing only `Goal`s in a specific date range might be better done outside `CollectionType`.

Comment: I could be quite wrong, actually! If editing (not deleting, or adding new) is the only concern for these `Goal`s in the route, maybe filtering which are presented based on date range is best done using [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)!

Comment: Thanks @CameronHurd. You are right, I have no need to add/delete goals in this application, I only need to edit existing goals. The form events idea is interesting, but hard to see how to apply to an entire array of entities and associated parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data), while avoiding the [`allow_add`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) and [`allow_delete`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) options for the `CollectionType` form might land you in the right neighbourhood:

First - let's assume we're filtering by year, for ease of example, and that the year is being scooped up from a `?y=2018` style of querystring. We'll pass that info down to the form builder:

```
<?php
// Inside a *Action method of a controller

public function index(Request $request): Response
{
    // ...
    $filteredYear = $request->get('y');
    $form         = $this->createForm(SiteGoalsAdminForm::class, $site, ['year_filter' => $filteredYear]);
    // ...
}
```

This implies we should be updating the default options for the `SiteGoalsAdminForm` class:

```
<?php

// SiteGoalsAdminForm.php

// ...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
          'data_class' => Site::class,
          'year_filter' => 2018
        ]);
     }
// ...
```

Then, in the `buildForm` method of that same class, we could access the `Site` object and remove `Goals` from it where the year of the goalDate did not fall inside the form's

```
<?php

// SiteGoalsAdminForm.php

namespace App\Form;

// ... other `use` statements, plus:
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class SiteGoalsAdminForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                /** @var Site */
                $site  = $event->getData();
                $goals = $site->getGoals();

                foreach ($goals as $g) {
                    if ($g->getGoalDate()->format('Y') !== (string) $options['year_filter']) {
                        $site->removeGoal($g);
                    }
                }

                $form->add('goals', CollectionType::class, [
                    'entry_type' => GoalsEmbeddedForm::class,
                ]);
            }
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Not a query_builder exactly, but functionally similar.

Comment: Wow, this is serious symfony form voodoo!! Thanks very much, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the results using the entity manager in the controller that you want to set on the collection type.

```
$goals = $entityManager->getRepository(Goals::class)->findBy(['year' => 2020]);
$form = $this->createForm(SiteGoalsType::class, $site, [
   'goals' => $goals
]);
```

Then configure the `SiteGoalsType::class` to accept new option goals.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Site::class,
    ]);
    $resolver->setRequired(['goals']);
}
```

In the `buildForm` method of `SiteGoalsType::class` Set the data to the collection type field from the options.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('goals', Type\CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => GoalsEmbeddedType::class,
        'data' => $options['goals'],
        'mapped` => false
    ]);
}
```

Make sure the add the `'mapped' => false` to your collection type field else it may lead to removing the records that didn't falls in the filter we have written in the controller.

```
$goals = $entityManager->getRepository(Goals::class)->findBy(['year' => 2020]);
```